# Crashlytics - How to distribute iMessage Sticker Pack extension

Tags: ios10, ios-app-extension, imessage

I have created an iMessage Sticker pack extension as a standalone product. Since the app doesn't have any Mac or iOS targets, How can I distribute it using Fabric / Crashlytics for beta testing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible at the moment, but farther workaround brought the next options:

- You can distribute it with Apple TF
- You can distribute your host app with your iMsg extension attached

Hope this helped